# How do I draw a line using Cocos2D-X?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I have been playing around with Cocos2D-X on my computer, and I have got it to build the hello world program on all the devices I would like to be able to build it on.

I know how to make the program display a sprite, and display a label, but I have not been able just to get the program to draw a line. How can I draw a line in Cocos2D-X?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `void ccDrawLine(const CCPoint& origin, const CCPoint& destination)` function declared in `CCDrawingPrimitives.h`

**Edit**

I've never tried using primitives myself. But as I know everything in `cocos2d` is rendered vis `CCNode` or it's subclass. So you must put your code inside `draw` method of some `CCNode` or it's subclass.

Comment: I've included CCDrawingPrimitives.h, and written ccDrawLine(CCPoint(0.3f, 0.3f), CCPoint(77.7f, 77.7f)); into my code, but I see no visual difference when I run the application. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: By the way. I faced with the following problem. I've wrote: `this->colorLayer->initWithColor( ccc4( 100, 100, 100, 255 ) )` so I didn't see anything drown with ccDrawLine because of Z-order. Then I just changed it to: `this->colorLayer->init();` and now all shows fine :)

Answer (score 7):

You must use `ccDrawLine` function in draw()

Example

```
void GameLayer::draw()
{
    //red line from bottom left to top right corner
    cocos2d::ccDrawColor4F(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cocos2d::ccDrawLine(ccp(0,0), ccp(100, 100));
}
```

And remember layer must be empty because it call first draw next it will draw children so if you have children it will overlap what you draw.

Z order :)

So in your code you have class

```
class MyLayer : public CCLayer
{
    ... //your code
    init()
    {
         CCLayer* pLayer = new GameLayer(); //It will be debug layer :)
     addChild(pLayer);//Alse you can set here Z order.
     pLayer->release();
    }
    virtual void draw()
    {
         //red line from bottom left to top right corner
         ccDrawColor4F(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
         ccDrawLine(ccp(0,0), ccp(100, 100));
    }
}
```

Above code will draw what you want.

Comment: If my Layer is not empty,I cannot draw.

Comment: You can but probably you will draw under your children. Change z-order of children. Or override visit and draw on the end

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am a little confused about multi-layers.

Comment: The `draw()` method has been changed in the latest version. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557033/cocos2d-x-v3-cannot-override-forward-function-draw

Answer (score 7):

I have found another easy way to draw line in CCLayer. Cocos2d-x has a class named CCDrawNode. You can check reference [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2/index.html). And it is very easy to use the function:

```
void drawSegment(const CCPoint & from,
    const CCPoint & to,
    float   radius,
    const ccColor4F & color 
)
```

Little example:

```
CCDrawNode* node = CCDrawNode::create();
addChild(node,10);//Make sure your z-order is large enough
node->drawSegment(fromPoint,toPoint,5.0,ccc4f(180,180,180,100));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
auto node = DrawNode::create();
node->drawLine(Vec2(200, 200), Vec2(200, 500), Color4F(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
this->addChild(node);
```

Answer (score 1):

In `cocos2d-x 3.0` alpha you can use

```
DrawPrimitives::drawLine(const cocos2d::Point &origin, const cocos2d::Point &destination);
```

Comment: You can, and should use cocos2d-x 3.x, IMHO, but `DrawPrimitives::drawLine(const cocos2d::Point &origin, const cocos2d::Point &destination);` isn't working OOTB. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22724319/866333