# cocos2d-x-3.0 draw vs onDraw

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm using cocos2d-x v3.0 and in some test project I'm doing some custom drawing by overriding `Node`'s `draw` method, but in the DrawPrimitives example provided they do something like this:

```
void DrawPrimitivesTest::draw()
{
    _customCommand.init(_globalZOrder);
    _customCommand.func = CC_CALLBACK_0(DrawPrimitivesTest::onDraw, this);
    Director::getInstance()->getRenderer()->addCommand(&_customCommand);
}

void DrawPrimitivesTest::onDraw()
{
    // drawing code here, why?
}
```

From reading the header and source files it seems like this may be some way of sending render commands straight to the renderer, is that correct?

Should I be using this method to do custom drawing? What's the difference between `draw` an `onDraw`?

**EDIT:**

As @Pedro Soares mentioned, since Cocos2D-X 3.0 you can't override `draw()` anymore. you have to use `draw(Renderer *renderer, const kmMat4 &transform, bool transformUpdated)` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In future, cocos2d-x 3.x renderer will be multithreaded with command pool.

`draw` method called by `visit` method, to create new command. When command is performed by command pool, `onDraw` is called. At this moment, commands are performed in single thread, but in overloaded `onDraw` method you should assume, that it will be called in another thread to simplify future migration.

Answer (score 10):

There is sample on cocos2d-x RC0 package that shows how to use the DrawPrimitives on top of other layers.

On your Layer .h add the following:

```
private:
    void onDrawPrimitives(const kmMat4 &transform, bool transformUpdated);
    CustomCommand _customCommand;
```

Now in the cpp of the Layer, override the layer draw method and include the onDrawPrimitives method:

```
void MyLayer::onDrawPrimitives(const kmMat4 &transform, bool transformUpdated)
{
    kmGLPushMatrix();
    kmGLLoadMatrix(&transform);

    //add your primitive drawing code here
    DrawPrimitives::drawLine(ccp(0,0), ccp(100, 100));
}

void MyLayer::draw(Renderer *renderer, const kmMat4& transform, bool transformUpdated)
{
    _customCommand.init(_globalZOrder);
    _customCommand.func = CC_CALLBACK_0(MyLayer::onDrawPrimitives, this, transform, transformUpdated);
    renderer->addCommand(&_customCommand);
}
```

Comment: Nice, but please change `MyLayer::onDraw` to `MyLayer::onDrawPrimitives`.

Comment: Is this the only benefit of overriding `onDrawPrimitives`. Blitting and stuff without getting bogged down in invalidation rectangles and cascading internal `onDraw` calls is one of the attractions of game development with cocos2d-x.

Answer (score 0):

I use draw method for debugDraw Like this It may be helpful

```
void HelloWorld::draw(Renderer *renderer, const Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags)
{
    Layer::draw(renderer, transform, flags);
    Director* director = Director::getInstance();
    GL::enableVertexAttribs(GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_POSITION );
    director->pushMatrix(MATRIX_STACK_TYPE::MATRIX_STACK_MODELVIEW);
    world->DrawDebugData();
    director->popMatrix(MATRIX_STACK_TYPE::MATRIX_STACK_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The draw() expression should be the same as the base class function.
The draw method of Node for cocos 3.3rc is:
virtual void draw(Renderer *renderer, const Mat4& transform, uint32_t flags);