# Cocos2d-x v3 Cannot override forward function Draw

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

```
//in my .h file
virtual void draw();

//in .cpp
void GameLayer:draw()
{
   Layer::draw();
   //draw code goes here
}
```

It shows cannot override forward function node::draw()

As far as I know, it was working on the old versions. Is there any new approach in cocos2d-x 3.0?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: m c++ is rusty but i think you just need to remove the .h declaration of the method, after all it's already declared in the node's header

Comment: No boss, removing from .h shows the same error on .cpp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in v3.0 overriding the draw() method has changed.

try in .h:

```
virtual void draw(Renderer* renderer, const kmMat4& transform, bool transformUpdated);
```

try in cpp:

```
void draw(Renderer* renderer, const kmMat4& transform, bool transformUpdated)
{

}
```

If you are running the latest version 3.1 from GitHub, this has changed. Replace `kmMat4` with `Matrix`

Edit: maybe you need to namespace it: `cocos2d::Renderer`

Comment: I recall trying this in my proj and getting `Renderer object not recognized` as if that object is local to `Node` in cocos2d and not exposed by importing the cocos2d.h

Comment: Can you somehow show me the errors? Renderer is very core. There should be no reason for it to not be "exposed"

Comment: If I try to override this method I just get `syntax error: identifier 'Renderer'` while having `#include cocos2d.h` at the top.